# Detached criteria - how to to specify join conditions

Tags: .net, sql, nhibernate, detachedcriteria

I am trying to retrieve some data from database using Nhibernate detached criteria. The problem is that I dont know how to specify the join conditions in Detached criteria. Please find my code below,

```
var criteria = DetachedCriteria.For<ExtraRiskQuestionAnswer>("extraRiskQuestionAnswer")
                .CreateAlias("RefRiskQuestion", "refRiskQuestion", JoinType.RightOuterJoin)
                .Add( Restrictions.Disjunction().
                     Add(Restrictions.Eq("CRMContactId", crmContactId))
                     .Add(Restrictions.IsNull("CRMContactId")));
```

This gets translated to -

```
SELECT refriskque1_.RefRiskQuestionId as y0_, refriskque1_.Question as y1_, this_.Answer as y2_ 
FROM FactFind.dbo.TExtraRiskQuestionAnswer this_ 
right outer join Administration.dbo.TRefRiskQuestion refriskque1_ on this_.RefRiskQuestionId=refriskque1_.RefRiskQuestionId 

WHERE this_.CRMContactId = 4670861 or this_.CRMContactId is null
```

But What I want is it should get translated to below.

```
SELECT refriskque1_.RefRiskQuestionId as y0_, refriskque1_.Question as y1_, this_.Answer as y2_ 
FROM FactFind.dbo.TExtraRiskQuestionAnswer this_ 
right outer join Administration.dbo.TRefRiskQuestion refriskque1_ on this_.RefRiskQuestionId=refriskque1_.RefRiskQuestionId 
and this_.CRMContactId = 4670861 or this_.CRMContactId is null
```

Any help much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NHiberante is really powerful. One of overloads of the method you used `CreateAlias` looks like this:

```
public DetachedCriteria CreateAlias(string associationPath
, string alias
, JoinType joinType
, ICriterion withClause);
```

The most interesting part in this case is the last **withClause**. This is in fact definition of conditions to be place directly into the JOIN clause

So what you should do is somehting like this:

```
var restriction = Restrictions.Disjunction()
  .Add(Restrictions.Eq("CRMContactId", crmContactId))
  .Add(Restrictions.IsNull("CRMContactId")));
```

And having this just adjust the defintion of the DetachedCriteria:

```
var criteria = DetachedCriteria.For<ExtraRiskQuestionAnswer>("extraRiskQuestionAnswer")
  .CreateAlias("RefRiskQuestion"
  , "refRiskQuestion"
  , JoinType.RightOuterJoin
  , restriction ) // HERE we go, that will be placed where you expected
```

And now you should have what you need. Other words, any additional restrictions for JOIN clause must be placed into **WithClause**
                .

Comment: Thanks a lot it worked. But we need to use extraRiskQuestionAnswer.CRMContactId in the restrictions as it couldn't able to resolve the CRMContactId.